# In C++14, in which scope are unscoped enumerators of redeclared enumerations declared?

Tags: c++, enums, c++14, language-lawyer

The C++14 (precisely, N4296) says with respect to enumerations, in 7.2:11:

> Each enum-name and each unscoped enumerator is declared in the scope
>   that immediately contains the enum-specifier.

Now what happens if a namespace N contains an opaque-enum-declaration of an enum E, and later the enumeration is fully declared from the global namespace? Shall we find its enumerators in the global namespace, or in the namespace N?

Of course, in order to opaque-declare an unscoped enumeration, it shall have a fixed underlying type. Consider the following piece of code.

```
namespace N { enum E : int; }
enum N::E : int {A,B};

namespace N {
    int foo() {
        return int(::N::B);
    }
}

int bar() {
    //return int(::A);
    return int(A);
}
```

The first line in `bar` is commented out, because `clang++ -std=c++14` says:

> no member named 'A' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'A'?

Gcc fails to compile both lines in bar(). So both gcc and clang declare the enumerations in the namespace `N`.

So my questions are:

1. What is the scope that immediatelly contains the enum specifier? (I thing it is the scope of the global namespace).
2. Should the enumerators `A`, `B` be defined in the global namespace?
3. In the `bar` function, why `::A` does not refer to the enumerator, but simple `A` does?
4. Why the expression `::N::B` in the function `N::foo` denotes the enumerator?

EDIT 1: the original declaration was `enum ::N::E : int {A,B};`, but gcc was not able to parse it ([bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83132)), so I removed the leading colons to use `enum N::E : int {A,B};`

EDIT 2: the clang's behavior is a [bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35401)

Comment: The successful compilation of `return int(A);` looks like [an obvious bug of *clang*](https://godbolt.org/g/6rjfZd).

Comment: Gcc does not even compile [the declaration](https://godbolt.org/g/VG1vBJ)

Comment: It it a bug in *gcc*, as I can see.

Comment: The gcc bug was [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83132)

Comment: Thank you! I think the bug in *clang++* is needed to be reported, too.

Comment: [Done](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35401).

Comment: Good. Could you add this link to your question or write an answer containing it?

Comment: I will add the link to the question. I will also check [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) whether it is a bug in standard as suggested in the clang bugzilla and then use the result to write an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159712/discussion-between-jan-tusil-and-constructor).

Comment: N4296 is a C++17 draft. The C++14 is N4140.

Comment: My opinion is that the enumerators should be in namespace `N` and the standard is defective.  More egregiously, imagine `namespace R { enum ::N::E : int { A, B }; }`. It makes no sense at all for `N::E`'s members to be `R::A` and `R::B`.

Comment: It was also discussed in the [isocpp.org google group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/embed/topic/std-discussion/_W1pUFzl3og/discussion); and it is in the [list of active issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1485).

Answer (score 2):

The enumeration E is declared within the namespace N, even though its definition is set within the global namespace. As such, it can only be accessed in the scope of N.

The bar function should then be defined as:

```
int bar() {
    return int(N::A);
    //SAME AS --> return int(::N::A);
}
```